# Communication between two Angular (ver 5, 8) apps (handshake)

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

What is a recommended approach for communication between 2 Angular apps?

App 1 is a product page for example, and App 2 is the cart.

One requirement is that orders are not persisted. Meaning we cannot call a service from app1 to create the order and retrieve it in app2. The order needs to be created in app2.

One way is using a POST from app1 to app2, but would like to look into other options.
I know localStorage is one, but any other better options out there or is that basically it?

Comment: They should not be different apps but modules loaded in the same application. Ideally they are modules where there is a host application (pick one or a new one) that loads the other.

Comment: unfortunately they're required to be different apps because 1 team is responsible for the cart and we have other teams that will interface with the cart (various other sales apps)

Comment: Modules with predefined interfaces can easily be developed simultaneously by multiple teams. The angular libraries are also created and maintained by multiple people / teams and all those items in the library are not each found in it's own application right? So why should you follow this paradigm?

Comment: I guess there are multiple apps following a micro front end approach, thus there is no putting those in a single app and the question is acutally valid.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a RESTful backend that both Angular apps share. Save and retrieve data as needed. Both apps work in perfect harmony.

**EDIT:**

I'm going to go into a bit further explanation.

SalesApp = Angular v5 sales app

CartApp = Angular v8 cart app

BackendAPI = A restful backend API

Lets say a user is browsing a product on the SalesApp. The user likes the product and clicks `Add to Cart`. The SalesApp POSTs to the BackendAPI.

```
POST cart/{productId}
```

Now the user is ready to check out. On the SalesApp, the user clicks the cart navigation. This loads up the CartApp. Upon CartApp load, we query for the cart items.

```
GET cart
```

This will get the items in the cart.

Comment: How would that work in the case where let's say we have app1 (sales page) add a product to be passed to app2 (cart page), where cart 2 creates the order with that product which was passed from app 1. How would the backend know what product was passed from app1? Unless we save some kind of token to localStorage and use that token to retrieve the product info once browser loads app2..hmm..

Comment: I'm remembering another requirement, which was that service is not persisted. Meaning we can't create an order until we're actually loading app2 :(